# Replace field names

Tags: ms-word, word-2007

I'm trying to use find and replace to change the value of a Field Name.

```
1_FirstName
1_LastName

Find and replace 1_ with 2_

2_FirstName
2_LastName
```

When I do this and click edit field, then the value is still 1_FirstName and 1_LastName yet it shows 2_FirstName and 2_LastName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT! Select the mergefields, turn on 'TOGGLE FIELD CODES', run the find/replace, switch back 'TOGGLE FIELD CODES' and click 'UPDATE FIELDS'. Works like a charm baby! :)

Answer (score 1):

If these are MERGEFIELD fields, roughly speaking, what gets replaced depends on what is visible when you do the Find/Replace. There's the underlying code, e.g.
{ MERGEFIELD 1_FirstName }
and the "chevron" version , e.g. <<1_FirstName>> (except with real chevrons rather than doubled-up < and >)

If you're seeing the chevron version and do the find/replace, the chevron version will change, but nothing useful has changed. If you select the field codes and F9 to update them, the "chevron name" will revert.

If you're seeing the { MERGEFIELD } version and do the find/replace, the field codes will be changed correctly , but the chevron display won't change until you select and update the fields (or perhaps move 1 record backwards/forwards in the preview or some such - OTTOMH I can't remember).

Comment: Oh boy, quite complicated :P So what I see is this: <<§1_FirstName§>> and the underlying code is §1_FirstName§. So I guess I'm seeing the Chevron codes? Is there a way to replace and update those?